# How to configure Logstash to take http requests from angularJS as input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logstash

I'm trying to configure logstash 1.5.1 to directly consume a $http.post request from an AngularJS application.

I found Logstash has a http{} input, but i'm unable to get it working.

Firstly http{} is not included in the default input plugins shipped with logstash, so how can I install it?

Secondly, how can I configure logstash to consume these POST request?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http input is included in [1.5.2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin).